# Do building codes enforce location with regard to plumbing rough-in?

Tags: plumbing, rough-in

We're building a new home and paid for the rough-in plumbing for a basement bathroom.  In the model, (which I have been told is not customizable outside their allotted plans) the roughed-in lines were along the stairway in a good location for a future bathroom.  When we were asked to do our pre-drywall walkthrough, we noticed that the drains were located more into the center of the basement which is totally different from the model and very inconvenient to add a bathroom without breaking up the concrete and moving 2 of the 3 drains.

When I asked the builder, they told me that "rough in" meant a rough location as well as no fixtures.  Since this is my 1st built home, I was wondering if the location of the plumbing is subject to any location in the basement? Bottom line, I want the drains where they were in the model.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I did not receive any prints nor was I asked to approve the location or told the location for the rough in was different from what was in the model. I have been told that I cannot change anything from what is offered in their plans as the house is "not a custom built home". Typically, can I request a copy of the basement plans as drawn?

Comment: Rough in means putting the plumbing exactly were is specified to be on the plans or otherwise instructed.

Comment: If you were offered to rough-in a bath in, say, an unfinished upstairs in a Cape Cod, they'd put sensibly the drain and hot and cold all in one place.  In the basement it should be no different.

Comment: *Typically* you'd have signed off on plans before construction began. What happens now is up to your builder, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

There are really no code requirements to be met with respect to location other than meeting clearances and that sort of thing. For example, a toilet must be so far from walls to the side. Anything else is a matter of prerogative and your contract.

It sounds like you have a contract dispute here, and that's off-topic on this network. If you approved a plan, and if the plumbing was installed according to plan, you'll have to fix it yourself. Otherwise, I'd expect the builder to do it.